# Sending shutdown command via ssh using sudo non-interactively

Tags: passwords, ssh, sudo

With iOS 12 and the new [Siri Shortcuts app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208309), I've been thinking of ways I could leverage the SSH command capability in the app. For those of you who don't know, the app allows you to send a bash file or string to `stdin` and returns `stdout` as a plain-text file, connecting using password authentication (no token authentication).

What I'd like to do is create a shortcut that executes `sudo shutdown [...]` on a remote server via the SSH command action. Since the action is non-interactive and non-tty I can't interactively enter the password, and I'm reluctant to put the password as plaintext in the action input string/`stdin`. On the other hand, I don't want to use `sudo -n` and `NOPASSWD` for the `shutdown` command, as that's a security risk that I don't want to deal with. I thought of perhaps requiring a random string for the `shutdown` message for `NOPASSWD` to be enabled in the `sudoers` file (i.e., `sudo shutdown -h now` would require a password, but `sudo shutdown -h now japos98vh92p3hoab982hfpa` would not), but I don't know if that's any more secure or even possible.

In summary, **how can I securely send a shutdown command over SSH using a non-interactive, non-tty session?**

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you've set the requirement "This must require a password" and also the requirement "I am not able to provide a password". From a security perspective, this seems like a pretty clear "Working as intended: you can't". If you're looking for tips using the Siri Shortcuts App for complex or higher-security SSH tasks, then that would be a StackOverflow / AskDifferent / SuperUser question.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth It's not "this must require a password" so much as "this must be secure"

Comment: Yeah, but "secure" by itself is not a thing, like, that doesn't grammar. You need to tell us what you're trying to be secure _against_. Check out [this handy questionnaire](https://www.eff.org/keeping-your-site-alive/evaluating-your-threat-model) to help you figure out your threat / risk model. The wording of your question seems pretty clear that `NOPASSWD` is _"a security risk that I don't want to deal with"_. Like, it sounds like you've set your security bar, then realized that your client can't meet it, and are stuck trying to make them fit together.

Comment: For example, whether your solution of`sudo shutdown -h now japos98vh92p3hoab982hfpa` meets your security requirements depends on what your security requirements are. The usual security model of `sudo` requires a hands-on-keyboard admin to type the password. Are you willing to weaken this to "_anybody with your phone_"? Or "_Anybody who can see your Siri history_"? Or "_Anybody who can see your bash history?_". Only you can decide what you consider "secure".

Comment: I'm being kinda sassy and I feel bad. I'll take a shot at writing a real answer.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth haha it's alright. I'm trying to learn and your feedback is helpful. I suppose I'm trying to secure against someone who has access to the command I send via SSH from being able to access my machine (i.e., by seeing a plaintext account password), yet still keeping a password prompt when using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using `NOPASSWD` and a random string. I added the following lines to my `sudoers` file:

```
matt  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now japos98vh92p3hoab982hfpa
matt  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot japos98vh92p3hoab982hfpa
```

This worked just like I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different questions in here, some of which are not security questions (for example "how to use sudo over a non-interactive SSH session" is really a programming / superuser question), and some of which only you can answer (what counts as "secure").

So instead of answering your question directly, I'll point out some security things to think about relating to your two proposals.

> I don't want to use `sudo -n` and `NOPASSWD` for the `shutdown` command, as that's a security risk that I don't want to deal with.

You may need to elaborate on what that security risk is and why you don't want to deal with it. Clearly you're OK with Siri knowing your username and password to SSH in, which, if the iOS devs were to build in a mechanism for handling `sudo` prompts or an attacker were to extract your username/passwd from Siri's storage, would be enough to perform any admin action on that machine.

The reason that `sudo` needs a password is to prevent you downloading malware in firefox, and then it turning itself into root. From the use-case you describe in your question, whether `ssh user@machine 'sudo cmd'` requires you to type your password once or twice doesn't make a difference from a security perspective; either the attacker knows your password, or they don't.

> `sudo shutdown -h now japos98vh92p3hoab982hfpa`

I don't know how you would accomplish this (but would love to learn if you can explain how in comments!). Skipping that (and any potential security holes you open in the process), I suppose this becomes a second admin password so that an attacker needs to know both your account password and this "admin password" in order to execute `shutdown`. This "admin password" will show up in more places: in plaintext in the Siri app, in the bash history for your user, in the process tree while it's running (try `ps -u`), and probably other places -- there's a reason things like `sudo` take passwords via stdin, not via command-line arguments.

So assuming

1. An attacker has gotten in to your account - either over SSH or because you downloaded malware in firefox and ran it
2. You have run this command before and it's in your bash history

I'm not sure there's any difference security-wise between this and setting `shutdown` to be `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: I've given a bit of a security analysis for your two proposals. Your question is really asking "Is there a way to do this?", which I don't know the answer to, and is really more of a "HowTo use this Siri app" question than a security question :/ As a security tester professionally, I'm usually better at breaking things than fixing them.

Comment: See my answer below for how I ended up accomplishing this.